# how to fix run time error 'segmentation fault' in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++14

This is code to find if a 2nd string is cipher of the 1st one or not.
To find it I am storing the encryption shift in another variable and then comparing all the corresponding letters of the strings to check if they have equal shift or not.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int q;
    cin>>q;
    int cip[q],flag[q];
    string s[q],t[q];
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        cin>>s[i];
        cin>>t[i];
    }
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        cip[i]=(s[i][1]+t[i][1])%26;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<s[i].size();i++){
            if((s[i][j]+t[i][j])%26==cip[i]){
                flag[i]=1;
            }
            else flag[i]=0;;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        if(flag[i]==1){
            cout<<cip[i];
        }
        else cout<<flag[i]-1;
    }
}
```

> runtime error: segmentation fault

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: I'm baffled - You have tagged your question c++14 yet you seem to be using none of its features.

Comment: your string is single-dimensional : string s[q]; but you are using s[] as two-dimensional in multiple places, this could be one of the reason!

Comment: Until you replace your variable length arrays with std::vector, this code is not legit c++.

Comment: This is not C. Please avoid tag spamming.

Comment: @ReturnZero no, it is an array of strings, the first `[]` indexes the array the second indexes the characters in the string.

Comment: Are the strings in `s` and `t` the same lengths? Please provide a [mre] with all the input strings you are using

Comment: Could you remove the variable-length arrays `int cip[q],flag[q]; string s[q],t[q];` and provide an example without it, e.g. using `std::vector`? This is not valid C++ and depending on the compiler could cause strange or undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This block of code is not correct:

```
for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<s[i].size();i++){
        if((s[i][j]+t[i][j])%26==cip[i]){
            flag[i]=1;
        }
        else flag[i]=0;;
    }
}
```

the line

```
for(int j=0;j<s[i].size();i++)
```

changing it to j++ should fix the segmentation fault.